# How to assign an unique value for the matching values in a table?

Tags: oracle10g

Description of my Question: 
how to assign an unique value for the matching values in a table?

I have sorted the columns which has same values in a table,like

AMOUNT    REF1    REF2   REF3      VALUE_DATE   ADDRESS

2000      asdfg  hjklq   werty    13-JAN-11 A

2500    asdfg   hjklq   werty    14-JAN-11  B

2500    asdfg   hjklq   werty    15-JAN-11  C

2500    asdfg   hjklq   werty    16-JAN-11  D

2000    asdfg   hjklq   werty    17-JAN-11  E

desired out: I need to update and assign an unique valufor matching values, like

AMOUNT   REF1    REF2    REF3    VALUE_DATE   ADDRESS  match_no

2000    asdfg   hjklq   werty    13-JAN-11  A   1

2500    asdfg   hjklq   werty    14-JAN-11  B   2

2500    asdfg   hjklq   werty    15-JAN-11  C   2

2500    asdfg   hjklq   werty    16-JAN-11  D   2

2000    asdfg   hjklq   werty    17-JAN-11  E   1

Same unique number should assign for matched value and update the match_no row as shown above..

Answer (score 1):

You can use analytic functions to rank the fields you want to find unique values across, then update the table with those values.  For this kind of scenario, where you're looking to set rows based on a matching query, `merge` is often more useful than `update`.

```
MERGE INTO   your_table
     USING   (SELECT   amount,
                       ref1,
                       ref2,
                       ref3,
                       DENSE_RANK()
                          OVER (ORDER BY amount,
                                         ref1,
                                         ref2,
                                         ref3)
                          AS rnk
                FROM   your_table) yt
        ON   (    your_table.amount = yt.amount
              AND your_table.ref1 = yt.ref1
              AND your_table.ref2 = yt.ref2
              AND your_table.ref3 = yt.ref3)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET match_no = rnk;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table temp_lookup as select x.*, rownum as match_no
  from (select amount, ref1, ref2, ref3 from yourtable
          group by amount, ref1, ref2, ref3) x;

update yourtable a set match_no = 
 (select match_no from temp_lookup b
    where a.amount = b.amount
      and a.ref1 = b.ref1
      and a.ref2 = b.ref2
      and a.ref3 = b.ref3)

drop table temp_lookup;
```